# Check Application Connectivity to Network, get list of specific application type C#

Tags: c#, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I plan to be running a host service of sorts.

I was curious to know if it would be possible to get a list of a specific application type, check it's connectivity to the network.. and if the application exceeds a certain rate.

Answer (score 0):

I had written C# article on how to check netowrk connectivity article.

you can just have a look in it. May be it will helps you

[Check Valid Network connection using C#](http://codingstuffsbykiran.blogspot.com/2009/11/check-for-valid-internet-connection.html)